# Why do we need a tag about Theo Jansen?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

Apparently we have a [tag now for Theo Jansen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/theo-jansen/info), a Dutch artist who creates kinetic sculptures. As he has no published works in fields of Science Fiction or Fantasy, Do we really need that tag?

It had no tag usage guide but I created one anyway. It has no usage at all<sup>1</sup>. And it is unlikely that it could be used in future for constructive on-topic questions.

Can we get rid of that tag?

---

<sub>1. Of course it was just created so that's natural. Also, I removed it from the question it was created for.</sub>

Comment: The tag now appears to be used on a total of 0 questions, so [meta-tag:status-completed]?. (For future reference, if a tag is only used on one or two questions and you're quite sure it shouldn't exist, it is but the work of a moment to edit it out yourself. It's good to seek meta consensus for more popular tags that would require bigger editing sprees to get rid of, or for tags whose existence is controversial in some way [e.g. if there was an edit war over them], but for a minor case like this ... well, SE gives you editing powers for a reason ;-) )

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes sorry I did not know about that. KutuluMike suggested that in the chat so I moved to remove it from the sole question it was used in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If such a Tag exists which is explicitly unrelated to fields of Science Fiction or Fantasy, has been used in very few to no questions and does not help in defining the topic of the question, Members should edit it out and leave the deletion work to Stack Exchange which automatically deletes unused tags.

As explained by [Rand al-Thor](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor):

> For future reference, if a tag is only used on one or two questions
>   and you're quite sure it shouldn't exist, it is but the work of a
>   moment to edit it out yourself.
>
> It's good to seek meta consensus for more popular tags that would
>   require bigger editing sprees to get rid of, or for tags whose
>   existence is controversial in some way [e.g. if there was an edit war
>   over them], but for a minor case like this ... well, SE gives you
>   editing powers for a reason.

Also explained on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it):

> There is a script that runs daily to hide (soft-delete) tags that
>   don't have any associated questions. All you need to do is remove the
>   tag from your question, and the script will pick it up automatically.

However if the tag is used in quite a few questions or is a center of controversy, take it to meta and seek consensus of the community first.

Comment: Why the community wiki?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well because It was basically your answer? Oh and by the way, should I delete this? Because there are plenty of other meta posts regarding the tags with no questions?

Comment: No need to delete it, but maybe edit it just to clarify that "such a tag". I.e. not *every* tag used only on very few questions should be deleted, but if you're sure it should go, then you can do it yourself and only take it to meta if someone disagrees.

Answer (score -2):

*As the user responsible for the tag, I'll describe my rationale for it.*

First of all, here's the question:
[What is the significance of the numbers in "The Eleven Holy Numbers of the Mechanical Soul"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139557/19561)

Now, as I've said before, I consider a tag to be a Bat-Signal for experts. The tags I put on a question are meant as a call on experts on those subjects.

The story I was asking about was written by Natalia Theodoridou. Her story was heavily influenced by the Dutch artist Theo Jansen, even going as far as naming her protagonist for him. It also features the same kind of kinetic sculptures he makes.

So when I considered the experts I needed for an answer, the two types of experts that came to mind were experts on the writer, Natalia Theodoridou, and experts on Theo Jansen.
Natalia Theodoridou, being a writer of SF & Fantasy, is of course on topic, so I created a tag for her. Since Theo Jansen is better known than Natalia Theodoridou (there's a Wikipedia article on him, while there is none on her) *and* because his work has — to me — a science fiction feel to it, I decided to create a tag for him as well.

This tag was challenged and removed from the question; I declined to pursue the tag any further.